# ASP Syntax Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm very new to ASP and am trying to figure out how to use some code I found on a site. The code is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387090.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

and is used to convert CSV values into an XML file. I've created an ASP file and copy and pasted the VB script into the file in between <% and %> tags but I get an error when I pull the page up (the page doesn't actually load).

I must be missing some simple syntax? Are those underscores supposed to be at the end of some of the lines? Here is the code that I am referring to:

```
' Create the text file.
Dim csvString As String = "GREAL,Great Lakes Food Market,Howard Snyder,Marketing Manager,(503) 555-7555,2732 Baker Blvd.,Eugene,OR,97403,USA" & vbCrLf & _
"HUNGC,Hungry Coyote Import Store,Yoshi Latimer,Sales Representative,(503) 555-6874,City Center Plaza 516 Main St.,Elgin,OR,97827,USA" & vbCrLf & _
"LAZYK,Lazy K Kountry Store,John Steel,Marketing Manager,(509) 555-7969,12 Orchestra Terrace,Walla Walla,WA,99362,USA" & vbCrLf & _
"LETSS,Let's Stop N Shop,Jaime Yorres,Owner,(415) 555-5938,87 Polk St. Suite 5,San Francisco,CA,94117,USA"
File.WriteAllText("cust.csv", csvString)

' Read into an array of strings.
Dim source As String() = File.ReadAllLines("cust.csv")
Dim cust As XElement = _
<Root>
    <%= From strs In source _
        Let fields = Split(strs, ",") _
        Select _
        <Customer CustomerID=<%= fields(0) %>>
            <CompanyName><%= fields(1) %></CompanyName>
            <ContactName><%= fields(2) %></ContactName>
            <ContactTitle><%= fields(3) %></ContactTitle>
            <Phone><%= fields(4) %></Phone>
            <FullAddress>
                <Address><%= fields(5) %></Address>
                <City><%= fields(6) %></City>
                <Region><%= fields(7) %></Region>
                <PostalCode><%= fields(8) %></PostalCode>
                <Country><%= fields(9) %></Country>
            </FullAddress>
        </Customer> _
    %>
</Root>
Console.WriteLine(cust)
```

I wrapped that in those ASP tags but it didn't work. This is copy and pasted directly from that site because I want to get it working before customizing it for my own use. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Underscores at the end of the line mean the string continues on the next line. It's VB.NET syntax. When you get an error, tell us what the error is.

Comment: Because there's a call to `Console.WriteLine` at the end, you should probably create a console application instead of an ASP.NET page.

Comment: Well I need it to be an .asp file for what I'm working on. @mason, how would I log an error?

Comment: Well, when you run the page, if there's an unhandled exception you'll probably get a big yellow screen that tells you what the error is. Then you tell us what that error is. If there's no unhandled exception, use your IDE's debugging tools to see how the program execution differs from what you think it should be.

Comment: I get a 500 internal error and the 'page cannot be displayed' error meaning there is some sort of syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you copied is for a console application. You'll need to do some more (little) work to get it to render in a web page.

The sample is written in VB and takes advantage of `xml literals` support. The code is written that way to distinguish "in line" code and literals (`<%= ...%>`). If you check the C# version it'll be apparent.

Trivial Example:

1. Create your `aspx` page (vb - so you can still do `xml literals`)

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="csvtoxml.aspx.vb" Inherits="csvtoxml" %>

    ...boiler plate aspx/web forms HTML stuff....

   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
           <p>This is where we will output the XML</p>
           <textarea runat="server" id="theXML" cols="70" rows="60"></textarea>
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
2. In code-behind (`xml literals`):

   ```
   Imports System.IO

   Partial Class csvtoxml
      Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       Me.theXML.InnerText = Me.MyFunc()
   End Sub

   Protected Function MyFunc() As String

       Dim csvString As String = "GREAL,Great Lakes Food Market,Howard Snyder,Marketing     Manager,(503) 555-7555,2732 Baker Blvd.,Eugene,OR,97403,USA" & vbCrLf & _
          "HUNGC,Hungry Coyote Import Store,Yoshi Latimer,Sales Representative,(503) 555-6874,City Center Plaza 516 Main St.,Elgin,OR,97827,USA" & vbCrLf & _
          "LAZYK,Lazy K Kountry Store,John Steel,Marketing Manager,(509) 555-7969,12 Orchestra Terrace,Walla Walla,WA,99362,USA" & vbCrLf & _
          "LETSS,Let's Stop N Shop,Jaime Yorres,Owner,(415) 555-5938,87 Polk St. Suite 5,San Francisco,CA,94117,USA"

          Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(MapPath("~/"), "cust.csv") 'Just adding this for debug (write permissions) in VS (local rights to file system)

          File.WriteAllText(filePath, csvString) 'Note: as above you can't just write on a server filesystem - ensure proper permissions

          ' Read into an array of strings.
          Dim source As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
          Dim cust As XElement = _
           <Root>
               <%= From strs In source _
                   Let fields = Split(strs, ",") _
                   Select _
                   <Customer CustomerID=<%= fields(0) %>>
                      <CompanyName><%= fields(1) %></CompanyName>
                      <ContactName><%= fields(2) %></ContactName>
                      <ContactTitle><%= fields(3) %></ContactTitle>
                      <Phone><%= fields(4) %></Phone>
                      <FullAddress>
                          <Address><%= fields(5) %></Address>
                          <City><%= fields(6) %></City>
                          <Region><%= fields(7) %></Region>
                          <PostalCode><%= fields(8) %></PostalCode>
                          <Country><%= fields(9) %></Country>
                      </FullAddress>
                  </Customer> _
               %>
           </Root>

       Return cust.ToString() 'Write XElement out to string

   End Function
   ```

### Result

```
<Root>
  <Customer CustomerID="GREAL">
    <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>
    <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>
    <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
    <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>
    <FullAddress>
      <Address>2732 Baker Blvd.</Address>
      <City>Eugene</City>
      <Region>OR</Region>
      <PostalCode>97403</PostalCode>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </FullAddress>
   </Customer>
 <Customer CustomerID="HUNGC">
    ...
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm trying to do this one step at a time as I'm completely confused with everything at this point. In #1, if I just take that code and put it in a webpage (and take out that line with the '...'; the notes you've put in there), that won't even display on the browser...there seems to be an error.

Comment: And for #2, do I put that in <% %> before the body tag?

Comment: @MxmastaMills The above sample is for an `aspx` WebForm and it companion `code-behind` page. I don't believe you can take advantage of `XML literals` in VB if you use "in line" coding (aka `<%  %>`)

Comment: And all I really need to do is create the XML as a string because I'm passing that as a variable through an API so I don't necessarily need it to display on a page, I just need it to be able to be written out.

Comment: @MxmastaMills Then refer to the `MyFunc()` Function and adjust as necessary.